# print format? which one is better python

Tags: python

I have always been curious

Why does python have different way to print stuff?

for example

```
print "this is ",a," and " ,b
```

vs

```
print "this is %d and %d" %(a,b)
```

Any performance issues? and stuff?

Comment: You don't include the third option of [.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).  Note that "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code."

Comment: Oh, and here's a previous question on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960442/difference-between-python-print-format-methods

Comment: These aren't really different ways to print stuff, per se. The second way you mention is just a string function. For instance, this would also work: `formatted = "this is %d and %d" % (a, b)`. The reason why you would choose the latter (or `str.format()`) instead of string concatenation is that it's much more flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 5):

There are many more ways to "print stuff" in Python, too, including the more modern [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) approach, `sys.stdout.write('foo')`, and probably others.

In terms of the difference between `print a, b, c` and `%` formatting, I generally use the former mostly for debugging output, when you just want spaces between a bunch of variables. When I want exact formatting or more control over the formatting, I use `%` (actually, these days I always use `str.format`).

For example:

```
print 'DEBUG:', var1, var2
```

Versus:

```
print 'Benchmarks took {0:.3f}s to run'.format(seconds)
```

Also, `%` and `str.format` formatting are much more general -- they don't actually print anything, they return a string, which you can print, write to a file, store in a database, send as a web response, etc.

Regarding performance -- just don't worry about it. All three are almost certainly fast, and premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I don't really want to post numbers (as that may encourage the wrong mindset), but `timeit` is so simple to use I couldn't help myself.

```
C:\>python -m timeit -s "import cStringIO; s = cStringIO.StringIO()"
                     "print >>s, 'this is', 'a', 'test'"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.39 usec per loop

c:\>python -m timeit -s "import cStringIO; s = cStringIO.StringIO()"
                     "print >>s, 'this is %s test' % 'a'"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 usec per loop

C:\>python -m timeit -s "import cStringIO; s = cStringIO.StringIO()"
                     "print >>s, 'this is {0} test'.format('a')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 usec per loop
```

I'm not quite sure why the `print a, b, c` approach is significantly slower, probably an implementation detail. But still, don't worry about it -- the time it takes to print to your file or screen probably far outweighs the string formatting part.

Comment: One thing I seem to recall about Python performance is that it's usually way more important to avoid interpreter overhead than microoptimising individual operations. That is, you want to avoid the overhead of doing function calls or looping over lists in Python, instead of figuring out the fastest way to add numbers or print strings.

Comment: @millimoose, I'm not sure that's quite right. For instance, `for s in strings: output += s` is a terribly slow way to concatenate strings, whereas `output = ''.join(strings)` is fast -- no thinking about bytecode. In optimizing Python code, I've almost never had to think about the interpreter. The exception is probably the overhead of calling Python functions, as you mention. For instance, `lst.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('foo'))` is much faster than `lst.sort(key=lambda x: x['foo'])`.

Comment: That's actually what I meant. That is, `for x in xs:` tends to be slower, because of the overhead of updating a local variable in the interpreter, than using `join()` or even `map()` or a comprehension. (All operations that work over the list "in one go".)

Comment: @millimoose: Well, yes, but that's actually a micro-optimization here. What's bad about using `output += s` in an inner loop is that it's quadratic O(N^2) because it has to construct/copy a new string each loop, whereas `str.join` is linear O(N). The issue of algorithmic complexity far outweighs interpreter concerns.

Answer (score 3):

The second method allows better formatting of your printed arguments. For example, you can specify to format a number as hexadecimal, or specify a number of decimals to be displayed of a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

The two are essentially the same. Python offers the formatting option so as to avoid the use of repeated commas in complex strings, which can become tedious to both type and read. Sometimes one will better suit a particular situation, sometimes the other will.

Comment: So there are no issues in using either format from performance point of view?

Comment: No there really isn't. Printing in general normally isn't too costly in terms of performance, and either one of these will work fine.

Comment: I wouldn't know of any performance differences between the two, but I would not worry about performance, unless you use print in one of your inner loops, which is a bad idea in itself.

Comment: @Fraz Odds are it's orders of magnitude more costly to render the printed string in the command prompt window than it is to format it. The same goes for writing it out to a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It is laso kind on an performance issue - not in time but in space.

These statements are equal:

```
print "this is ",a," and " ,b
sys.stdout.write("this is ");sys.stdout.write(" ");sys.stdout.write(str(a));sys.stdout.write(" ");sys.stdout.write(" and ");sys.stdout.write(str(b));sys.stdout.write("\n");
```

And those are equal:

```
print "this is %d and %d" %(a,b)
sys.stdout.write("this is %d and %d" %(a,b));sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Usually if you print many elements the first version is considered faster because one after the other ir written to the stream.

The second version needs to process and copy parts of the string `"this is %d and %d"`. So if you have many elements in there and you format many times and the string is big it can use up more memory than version 1.

But because Python is pretty high level I can not say for sure what performes better.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to give a shout out to the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module while we're talking about ways to print things.

```
import logging
# call once per process
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# do this when you would print
logging.info('this is %d and %d', a, b)
```

As simple as print but really easy to configure for logging to files with auto-rotation by date, custom formatting, etc., when you suddenly realize "oh, this project is here to stay."